# changing a map property in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an image swap for another image in javascript on hover. I also want the second image to contain a map. I can get either to work, but not both at the same time

```
<html>

<A   onMouseOver="SwapOut()" onMouseOut="SwapBack()">
<IMG NAME="imageflip"   SRC="one.jpg"   WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=200 BORDER=0></A>

<map name="regionmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,100" alt="foo" href="foo.html">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,100,200,200" alt="bar" href="bar.html">
</map>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- hide from none JavaScript Browsers

Image1= new Image(200,200)
Image1.src = "one.jpg"
Image2 = new Image(200,200)
Image2.src = "two.jpg"



function SwapOut() {
document.imageflip.src = Image2.src; 
document.imageflip.useMap = "#regionmap";

return true;
}

function SwapBack() {
document.imageflip.src = Image1.src; return true;

}

// - stop hiding -->
</SCRIPT> 




</html>
```

So in a browser I get the map but not the changing image. If I comment out the `document.imageflip.useMap = "#regionmap";` part then the image swap code works. I'm a noob to js...thanks everyone

Comment: `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">`, `<IMG NAME="imageflip"   SRC="one.jpg"   WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=200 BORDER=0>`?  How old is this code?

Comment: I don't know. A friend sent me the image swapping code, I was trying to get the map to work. Presuming you are not telling me it has 'gone off' are you saying it is obsolete?

Comment: Well, using `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">` is pretty obsolete nowadays, you can just use `<script>`.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Script

Comment: And with `<IMG WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=200 BORDER=0>`, you should use CSS for them.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img

Comment: I know about the CSS, but I don't think that is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks to be that you are actually hovering your mouse over the `<map>` element, not the `<a>` element.

So, what's happening is that `SwapOut()` is triggering and setting the `<map>` and then `SwapBack()` is immediately triggering because you are now hovering over the `<map>` and not the `<a>`.

To fix it, I added the events to the `<map>` element as well as the `<a>`.

```
<A onMouseOver="SwapOut()" onMouseOut="SwapBack()">
  <IMG NAME="imageflip" SRC="one.jpg" WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=200 BORDER=0>
</A>

<map name="regionmap" onMouseOver="SwapOut()" onMouseOut="SwapBack()">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,100" alt="foo" href="foo.html">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,100,200,200" alt="bar" href="bar.html">
</map>
```

I'm not sure if it's needed, but I also added `document.imageflip.useMap = null;` to `SwapBack()`.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/8968zL0v/

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense